# Change variable inside function foreach loop

Tags: php, function, variables, foreach, global

I've a problem that i can't solve. I think it's an easy fix, but after 3 hours of searching and trail-error. I've decided to ask the question over here:

This is my time function for a schedule application.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
$current_time = time();
$unixtime = $current_time;
$time = date("Gi",$unixtime);

global $time;

function time_left($time, $active_class, $maxtime, $mintime){
    if($time < $maxtime and $time > $mintime){
                global $active_class;
        $active_class = 'active';
        echo 'succes!';
    }
}
```

Here is my foreach loop, i loop through an array

```
foreach($rows as $row){
switch($hours){
 case 1:
    $t = '8:45 - 9:15';
    $mintime = 845;
    $maxtime = 914;
    time_left($time, $maxtime, $mintime);
  break;
 case 2:
    $t = '8:45 - 9:15';
    $mintime = 845;
    $maxtime = 914;
    time_left($time, $maxtime, $mintime);
  break;

  /* etc.. etc.. etc... */

}   
  echo "<li class='" . $active_class ."'>";
  echo "<div class='right'></div>";
  echo "<div class='hour'>", $times, "</div><span class='divider-time'>|</span>";

  $hours++;
  $i = 0;
  foreach($row[$day] as $r[1]){
    $i++;
    if ($i == 1) {
      $class = 'vk';
   } elseif ($i == 2) {
   $class = 'lok';
   } elseif ($i == 3) {
   $class = 'doc';
   }
    echo "<span class='" . $class . "'>", $r[1],  "</span>";
   }
     echo "</li>";
     $class++;
}
```

I get the 'succes!' echo on the right location. But the active class is not working properly. The idea behind it is that the active class is only shown on one row. Now it searches for a match and everything behind it also gets the active class.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should restart the `$active_class` variable in every iteration.
Otherwise, once it is set to `active` it won't change its value again.

```
foreach($rows as $row){
    $active_class = '';

    //YOUR CODE HERE
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was just that simple!

Comment: If it worked well you can accept the answer in a few minutes :)